# How can I concatenate two cell arrays of strings and keep the spaces in matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cells

Say I have a cell arrays like

```
a = {'abcde', 'fghi'};
b = {'jkl', 'mn'};

ab = strcat(a, b)
ab = 

    'abcdejkl'    'fghimn'
```

But I do not want `'abcdejk'`, I need `'abcde jkl'`    and also `' fghi mn'`
with that little space there

Answer (score 4):

Add a space cell by using `ab = strcat(a,{' '},b)`

Comment: Ah, yes. +1 I misread the question.